# How to rotate a 3D axis? Some options of the axis doesn't work

Tags: pgfplots, axis

I have a graph with modified directions axis. I want to use `view` option of the `axis` to rotate the graph, because I want to show better the OAP plane. But it doesn't work. The scales of the three axis change, even when I use `axis equal` and `scale mode=scale uniformly` options.

Even so, I want to comprehend how `x=...`, `y=...`, `z=...` works. I know about unit vectors, but I don't understand this code. There is no much explanation how it works, in the manual. Please someone who helps me with the code to solve and the explanation.

This is the code for the graph which I want to modify.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{per-mode = symbol}
\begin{document}
 \begin{figure}[htbp!]
     \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis} [axis lines=center, axis equal,
            x={(.5cm,-0.1cm)}, y={(0cm,0.5cm)}, z={(-0.3cm,-0.3cm)},
            scale mode=scale uniformly,
            xlabel={$x$},
            ylabel={$y$},
            zlabel={$z$},%axis equal=true,
            xmax=6, ymax=4, zmax=7,
            ticks=none,
            clip=false, scale=2, view={0}{90},
            ]
            \addplot3+ [no marks,blue] coordinates { (0,0,0) (4,0,0) (4,0,4) (0,0,4) (0,0,0)};
            \addplot3+ [no marks,blue] coordinates { (0,2,0) (4,2,0) (4,2,4) (0,2,4) (0,2,0)};
            \addplot3+ [no marks,blue,solid] coordinates { (0,0,0) (0,2,0)};
            \addplot3+ [no marks,blue,solid] coordinates { (4,0,0) (4,2,0)};
            \addplot3+ [no marks,blue,solid] coordinates { (4,0,4) (4,2,4)};
            \addplot3+ [no marks,blue,solid] coordinates { (0,0,4) (0,2,4)};
            \node [only marks] at (0,2,4)[above left] {$P(0,2,4)$};
            \filldraw [gray] (0,2,4) circle [radius=2pt];
            \filldraw [fill=gray!10, draw=green!10!black] (0,0,0) -- (0,2,4) -- (4,2,0) -- (0,0,0);
            \node [only marks] at (0,0,0)[below] {$O$};
            \node [only marks] at (4,2,0)[above] {$A(4,2,0)$};
            \draw [very thick] (0,0,0) -- (4,2,0) node [midway, sloped, below] {$y=0.5x$};
            \draw[|{latex}-{latex}|] (4.2,0,4)--(4.2,0,0)
    node [midway,sloped, below] { \SI{4}{mm}};
    \draw[|{latex}-{latex}|] (0,-.2,4)--(4,-.2,4)
    node [midway,sloped, below] { \SI{4}{mm}};
    \draw[|{latex}-{latex}|] (4.2,0,0)--(4.2,2,0)
    node [midway,sloped, below] { \SI{2}{mm}};
        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Paralelepípedo}
\label{planoP}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

In my opinion this is a tikz drawing, better than a pgfplots one. That said, first things first. So, for the meaning of `x=..., y=..., z=...`. When we assign some values to x, y and z we are defining three unit vectors in the 2D plane which are the references for a 3D drawing. If we write `x={(0.5cm,-0.1cm)},y={(0cm,0.5cm)},z={(-0.3cm,-0.3cm)}`, then we are setting these vectors as the unit vectors for the x, y and z axes, what a physicist would call `\vec i, \vec j, \vec k` or `\mathbf{i},\mathbf{j},\mathbf{k}` (whatever). If we want to represent the point B(1,2,0) we need to move from the origin once time the amounts `x=(0.5,-0.1)` and then twice times the amounts `y=(0,0.5)`, and the point B in the 2D plane will be at

```
(0.5,-0.1) + 2(0,0.5) = (0.5,0.9)
```

[image]

There is a problem with the perspective though. It is not a problem in this example but it could be for a slightly more complex drawing. Suppose we need to draw a sphere in 3D with radius 2, and that we define the axis as above: `x={(0.5cm,-0.1cm)},y={(0cm,0.5cm)},z={(-0.3cm,-0.3cm)}`. Then approximating by hand we can obtain the following picture, when the red curves are the circles of intersection of the sphere and the coordinate planes (with radius 2), and the blue curve is the (not so well) approximate sphere.
[image]

The problem here is that for an axonometric perspective each axis will need an appropriate reduction ratio, and we have to compute these ratios. There are many options to do that. For example, there are online calculators (I use http://tamivox.org/redbear/axono/index.html), there is the `tikz-3dplot` library, etc.

If we compute the appropriate axis with reduction ratios, we can obtain the following code:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage    {tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,
%x={(0.5cm,-0.1cm)},y={(0cm,0.5cm)},z={(-0.3cm,-0.3cm)}                 % original axes
x={(0.9150cm,-0.1779cm)},y={(0cm,0.8976cm)},z={(-0.4034cm,-0.4034cm)}  % something approximate but with corrected reduction
%x={(0cm,0.8976cm)},y={(-0.9150cm,0.1779cm)},z={(-0.4034cm,-0.4034cm)}  % rotated axes
]
% Grids
\draw[canvas is xy plane at z=0,help lines] (0,0) grid (3,3);
\draw[canvas is xz plane at y=0,help lines] (0,0) grid (3,3);
\draw[canvas is yz plane at x=0,help lines] (0,0) grid (3,3);
% Axes
\draw [-latex] (0,0,0) -- (4,0,0) node [right] {$x$};
\draw [-latex] (0,0,0) -- (0,4,0) node [above] {$y$};
\draw [-latex] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,4) node [left]  {$z$};
% Circles
\draw[canvas is xy plane at z=0,red] (0,0) circle (2);
\draw[canvas is xz plane at y=0,red] (0,0) circle (2);
\draw[canvas is yz plane at x=0,red] (0,0) circle (2);
% Sphere
%\draw[blue] (0,0) circle (1.2 cm); % I'm trying to approximate the radius by hand
\draw[blue] (0,0) circle (2 cm);
% B point
%\draw[red,->] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node [midway, below] {$\vec i$};
%\draw[red,->] (1,0,0) -- (1,2,0) node [midway, right] {$2\vec j$};
%\fill (1,2,0) circle (1pt) node [above right] {$B$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Now your drawing. If I understand the rotation you need (around z axis), we only need to assign to the y vector the coordinates of the negative old x vector, and to assign to the x vector the old y vector (commented rotated axes in the precedent code). Then, if we draw (with tikz) the orthoedron, we can get something like this:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage    {siunitx}  % to manage SI units
\usepackage    {tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}       % for the "canvas is..." options
\usetikzlibrary{babel}    % not necessary in this example, but just in case...

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,x={(0cm,0.8976cm)},y={(-0.9150cm,0.1779cm)},z={(-0.4034cm,-0.4034cm)}]
% Axes
\draw [-latex] (0,0,0) -- (5,0,0) node [right] {$x$};
\draw [-latex] (0,0,0) -- (0,5,0) node [above] {$y$};
\draw [-latex] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,5) node [below]  {$z$};
% Hidden lines
\draw[blue,dashed] (0,2,4) -- (0,2,0) -- (4,2,0);
% OAP plane
\draw[green!50!black,fill=green,fill opacity=0.2] (0,0,0) -- (4,2,0) -- (0,2,4) -- cycle;
% Rectangles (faces)
\draw[canvas is xy plane at z=4,blue,fill=blue,fill opacity=0.1] (0,0) rectangle (4,2);
\draw[canvas is yz plane at x=4,blue,fill=blue,fill opacity=0.1] (0,0) rectangle (2,4);
\draw[canvas is xz plane at y=0,blue,fill=blue,fill opacity=0.1] (0,0) rectangle (4,4);
% Labels
\fill (0,0,0) circle (1pt) node [above right] {$O$};
\fill (4,2,0) circle (1pt) node [above]       {$A(4,2,0)$};
\fill (0,2,4) circle (1pt) node [left]        {$P(0,2,4)$};
% Dimensions
\begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0,red]
  \draw (0,-0.1) -- (0,-0.5);
  \draw (4,-0.1) -- (4,-0.5);
  \draw[<->] (0,-0.4) -- (4,-0.4) node[midway,rotate=90,yshift={-2mm}] {\SI{4}{mm}};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=0,red]
  \draw (-0.1,4) -- (-0.5,4);
  \draw[<->] (-0.4,0) -- (-0.4,4) node[midway,rotate=45,yshift={-2mm}] {\SI{4}{mm}};
  \draw (2,4.1) -- (2,4.5);
  \draw[<->] (0,4.4) -- (2,4.4) node[midway,rotate=-10,yshift={-2mm}] {\SI{2}{mm}};;
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use `3dtools` at [here](https://github.com/marmotghost/tikz-3dtools) and try this code.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,3dtools}% https://github.com/marmotghost/tikz-3dtools
\begin{document}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,c/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=1pt}, 3d/install view={phi=30,psi=0,theta=70}]
            \path
             (0,0,0) coordinate (O)
            (4,0,0) coordinate (B)
            (4,2,0) coordinate (A)
            (0,2,0) coordinate (D)
            (0,0,4) coordinate (O')
            (4,0,4) coordinate (B')
            (4,2,4) coordinate (A')
            (0,2,4) coordinate (P);
\path foreach \p/\g in {A/-90,B/-90,O/-90,D/-90,O'/180,B'/90,A'/90,P/90}{(\p)node[c]{}+(\g:2.5mm) node{$\p$}}; 
\draw[3d/visible] (O') -- (O) -- (B) -- (A) 
(B') -- (A') -- (P) -- (O') -- cycle
(B) -- (B') (A) -- (A')  ;
\draw[3d/hidden] (O) -- (D) -- (A)
(D) -- (P) (O) -- (A) -- (P) -- cycle
;
\draw[-latex,3d/visible] (O') -- (0,0,5.5) node[anchor=south]{$z$};
\draw[-latex,3d/visible] (B) -- (6,0,0) node[anchor=south]{$x$};
\draw[-latex,3d/hidden] (D) -- (0,4,0) node[anchor=south]{$y$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or you can use

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,3dtools}% https://github.com/marmotghost/tikz-3dtools
\begin{document}
\foreach \Angle in {5,15,...,355}
{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,c/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=1pt}, 3d/install view={phi=\Angle,psi=0,theta=70},same bounding box=A]
            \path
             (0,0,0) coordinate (O)
            (4,0,0) coordinate (B)
            (4,2,0) coordinate (A)
            (0,2,0) coordinate (D)
            (0,0,4) coordinate (O')
            (4,0,4) coordinate (B')
            (4,2,4) coordinate (A')
            (0,2,4) coordinate (P)
            (2,1,2) coordinate (T)
            ;   \tikzset{3d/polyhedron/.cd,O={(T)},fore/.append style={fill=none},
                back/.append style={3d/hidden},
                draw face with corners={{(O)},{(B)},{(A)},{(D)}},
                draw face with corners={{(A)},{(B)},{(B')},{(A')}},
                draw face with corners={{(O)},{(D)},{(P)}},draw face with corners={{(O)},{(O')},{(P)}},
                draw face with corners={{(A')},{(B')},{(O')},{(P)}},
                draw face with corners={{(A)},{(D)},{(P)}},
                draw face with corners={{(A)},{(A')},{(P)}},
                draw face with corners={{(O)},{(B)},{(B')},{(O')}}}
\path foreach \p/\g in {A/-90,O/-90,P/90}{(\p)node[c]{}+(\g:2.5mm) node{$\p$}}; 
\draw[3d/hidden]  (O) -- (A) ;
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This code from marmot

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,3dtools}% https://github.com/marmotghost/tikz-3dtools
\begin{document}
    \foreach \Angle in {5,15,...,355}
    {
        \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,
            c/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=1pt}, 
            3d/install view={phi=\Angle,theta=70},same bounding box=A]
            \path (1,0,0) coordinate (ez) (0,1,0) coordinate (ex)
            (0,0,1) coordinate (ey);
            \begin{scope}[x={(ex)},y={(ey)},z={(ez)}] 
                \draw[-stealth] (0,0,0) -- (5,0,0) node[pos=1.05]{$x$};
                \draw[-stealth] (0,0,0) -- (0,5,0) node[pos=1.05]{$y$};
                \draw[-stealth] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,5) node[pos=1.05]{$z$};
                \path
                (0,0,0) coordinate (O)
                (4,0,0) coordinate (B)
                (4,2,0) coordinate (A)
                (0,2,0) coordinate (D)
                (0,0,4) coordinate (O')
                (4,0,4) coordinate (B')
                (4,2,4) coordinate (A')
                (0,2,4) coordinate (P)
                (2,1,2) coordinate (T);   
                \tikzset{3d/polyhedron/.cd,O={(T)},fore/.append style={fill=none},
                    back/.append style={3d/hidden},
                    draw face with corners={{(O)},{(B)},{(A)},{(D)}},
                    draw face with corners={{(A)},{(B)},{(B')},{(A')}},
                    draw face with corners={{(O)},{(D)},{(P)}},draw face with corners={{(O)},{(O')},{(P)}},
                    draw face with corners={{(A')},{(B')},{(O')},{(P)}},
                    draw face with corners={{(A)},{(D)},{(P)}},
                    draw face with corners={{(A)},{(A')},{(P)}},
                    draw face with corners={{(O)},{(B)},{(B')},{(O')}}}
                \path foreach \p/\g in {A/-90,O/-90,P/90}{(\p)node[c]{}+(\g:2.5mm) node{$\p$}}; 
                \draw[3d/hidden]  (O) -- (A) ;
            \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. But, for convinience, I want to show the axis directions as the figure. I think this is the hard part.