# How can I draw this cylinder with TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to draw this. I would appreciate it if someone would help me to draw this.[image]

Comment: You can see [here](https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=1659)

Comment: Or [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/595476/draw-a-wedge-with-circular-base-in-tikz)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I put `\Angle` as the angle of `phi`, and I consider two cases `\Angle` from 0 to 180, and `\Angle` from 180  to 360.
For example, with `\Angle = 70`

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3dtools,calc}%https://github.com/marmotghost/tikz-3dtools
\begin{document}
    \foreach \Angle in {70}
    {\begin{tikzpicture}[3d/install view={phi=\Angle,theta=70},line cap=round,line join=round,c/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=1pt},
            declare function={R=2;h=4;}]     
        \path[save named path=cyl] pic{3d/frustum={R=R,r=R,h=h}};
\draw[3d/hidden] plot[smooth,domain=180-\Angle+\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/3d/phi}:\Angle] ({R*cos(\x)},{R*sin(\x)},{R*sin(\x)});
\draw[3d/visible] plot[smooth,domain=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/3d/phi}:0] ({R*cos(\x)},{R*sin(\x)},{R*sin(\x)});        
    \draw[3d/hidden] (0:R)  -- (180:R);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can use like that

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3dtools,calc}%https://github.com/marmotghost/tikz-3dtools
\begin{document}
    \foreach \Angle in {5,10,...,175}
    {\begin{tikzpicture}[3d/install view={phi=\Angle,theta=70},line cap=round,line join=round,c/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=1pt},
            declare function={R=2;h=4;}]     
        \path[save named path=cyl] pic{3d/frustum={R=R,r=R,h=h}};
\draw[3d/hidden] plot[smooth,domain=180-\Angle+\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/3d/phi}:\Angle] ({R*cos(\x)},{R*sin(\x)},{R*sin(\x)});
\draw[3d/visible] plot[smooth,domain=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/3d/phi}:0] ({R*cos(\x)},{R*sin(\x)},{R*sin(\x)});        
    \draw[3d/hidden] (0:R)  -- (180:R);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With `\Angle = 300`, my code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3dtools,calc}%https://github.com/marmotghost/tikz-3dtools
\begin{document}
\foreach \Angle in {300}
{\begin{tikzpicture}[3d/install view={phi=\Angle,theta=70},line cap=round,line join=round,c/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=1pt},
        declare function={R=2;h=4;}]     
        \path[save named path=cyl] pic{3d/frustum={R=R,r=R,h=h}};
        \draw[3d/hidden] plot[smooth,domain=0:\Angle-180] ({R*cos(\x)},{R*sin(\x)},{R*sin(\x)});
        \draw[3d/visible] plot[smooth,domain=\Angle-180:180] ({R*cos(\x)},{R*sin(\x)},{R*sin(\x)}); 
        \draw[3d/hidden] (0:R)  -- (180:R);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or you can use

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3dtools,calc}%https://github.com/marmotghost/tikz-3dtools
\begin{document}
\foreach \Angle in {185,190,...,355}
{\begin{tikzpicture}[3d/install view={phi=\Angle,theta=70},line cap=round,line join=round,c/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=1pt},
        declare function={R=2;h=4;}]     
        \path[save named path=cyl] pic{3d/frustum={R=R,r=R,h=h}};
        \draw[3d/hidden] plot[smooth,domain=0:\Angle-180] ({R*cos(\x)},{R*sin(\x)},{R*sin(\x)});
        \draw[3d/visible] plot[smooth,domain=\Angle-180:180] ({R*cos(\x)},{R*sin(\x)},{R*sin(\x)}); 
        \draw[3d/hidden] (0:R)  -- (180:R);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It worked out fine!!!

Comment: Can you accept the answer?