# Truncated parabolic cylinder

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-3dplot, tikz-3d

I would like to know if it is possible to draw an image like this in 3D using tikz? Am not acquainted yet with 3D diagrams in TikZ and I would like to draw something like the picture attached. Does anybody have any helpful hints?
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome. // You can do it in 2D, when you approach this task as an artist. Just translate your pencil strokes into Tikz commands. To use fills and opacity later you need to close paths. // All you need for the first part you can obtain from the tutorials at the beginning of the pgfmanual, including fills. Transparency etc. are discussed in detail further down in said manual.

Comment: you can see this post https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/595476/draw-a-wedge-with-circular-base-in-tikz/630795#630795