# Boxing bag not an ovoid shape

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to make the following boxing bag scheme:

[image]

I do not know how to code the shape of the bag and how to plot the supporting chain and the wall structure.
I have found this entry [How can I draw an egg using TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74168/how-can-i-draw-an-egg-using-tikz)
but it is not the same shape of the boxing bag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a starting point. All is made with lines, circles and arcs, but the key here are the `scopes` to draw each part of the picture. And, in some cases the `canvas` provided by the 3d library.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage    {tikz}
\usepackage    {siunitx} % SI units, \SI and \ang commands
\usetikzlibrary{3d}      % For "canvas is..." options
\usetikzlibrary{babel}   % There are issues with some babel packages
\usetikzlibrary{calc}    % Computing some coordinates (adding them, in this example)

% isometric axes
\pgfmathsetmacro\xx{1/sqrt(2)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\xy{1/sqrt(6)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\zy{sqrt(2/3)}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(\xx cm,-\xy cm)},y={(\xx cm,\xy cm)},z={(0 cm,\zy cm)},%
                    thick,line cap=round,line join=round]
% some dimensions
\def\br{1.5}  % bag radius
\def\be{4}    % bag elevation
\def\we{17.6} % wall structure elevation
\def\ws{4}    % wall structure separation
% Wall & floor
\fill[canvas is yz plane at x=-\ws,gray!20] (-1.2*\ws,0)    rectangle (1.2*\ws,\we+1);
\fill[canvas is xy plane at z=0   ,gray!10] (-\ws,-1.2*\ws) rectangle (6,1.2*\ws);
\draw[dashed] (0,0,\be) -- (0,0,0) -- (\ws,0,0)  node[midway,sloped, below] {\SI{40}{cm}};
\fill[canvas is xy plane at z=0,gray] (\ws,0) circle (0.25) node[black,xshift=1.25cm] {Boxing Spot};
% Bag
\draw[fill=white] ($(-135:\br)+(0,0,\be+9.6)$) --++ (0,0,-9.6)
    {[canvas is xy plane at z=\be] arc (-135:45:\br)} -- ($(45:\br)+(0,0,\be+9.6)$);
\draw[canvas is xy plane at z=\be+9.6,fill=white] (0,0) circle (\br);
\foreach[count=\xi]\i in{1.5,4.2,6.9} 
{%                       1.5, 1.5+2.7, 1.5+2.7+2.7
  \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=\be+\i]
    \draw[orange] (0,0) circle (\br);
    \fill[orange] (0,0,\be+\i) circle (1pt);
    \coordinate   (C\xi) at (225:\br+0.2);
  \end{scope}
}
\foreach\i in {0,90,180,270}
{%
  \draw[line width=0.5mm] ($(\i:\br)+(0,0,\be+9.6)$) -- (0,0,\we-0.15);
}
\draw[line width=0.5mm] (0,-\br,\be+9.6) --++ (0,0,-0.5);
\draw[line width=0.5mm] (\br, 0,\be+9.6) --++ (0,0,-0.5);
% Wall structure
\begin{scope}[shift={(-\ws,0,\we)},line width=1.5mm]
  \draw (0.5*\ws ,0,0) -- (0,0,-0.5*\ws) -- (0,0,-\ws);
  \draw (0,-0.5*\ws,0) -- (0,0.5*\ws,0);
  \draw (0,0,0)        -- (1.25*\ws,0,0);
  \draw[canvas is xz plane at y=0,line width=0.75mm] (\ws,-0.15) circle (0.15);
\end{scope}
% Bag dimensions
\begin{scope}[rotate around z=45,canvas is xz plane at y=0]
  \draw[blue,<->] (2*\br,\be) --++ (0,1.5) node [midway,right] {\SI{15}{cm}};
  \foreach\i in {0,1,2}
  {%
    \draw[blue,dashed] (  \br,\be+1.5+2.7*\i) --++ (\br,0);
    \draw[blue,<->]    (2*\br,\be+1.5+2.7*\i) --++ (0,2.7) node [midway,right] {\SI{27}{cm}};
  }
  \draw[blue,dashed] (\br,\be)     --++ (\br,0);
  \draw[blue,dashed] (\br,\be+9.6) --++ (\br,0);
  \draw[blue] (3*\br,\be+6.9) --++ (0.5,0) --++ (0,-2.7) node [midway,right] {Punch Section} --++ (-0.5,0);
\end{scope}
% section
\begin{scope}[x={(1cm,0cm)},y={(0cm,1cm)},shift={(-8,6)},very thick]
  \foreach\i in {1,2,3}
  {%
    \draw[blue,-latex] (0,0) -- (C\i);
  }
  \draw[fill=white] (0,0) circle (3);
  \draw[blue,<->] (-60:0.5) arc (-60:60:0.5) node [midway,right] {\ang{120}};
  \foreach\i in {60,180,300}
  {%
    \begin{scope}[rotate=\i]
      \draw[gray,dashed] (0,0) -- (3,0);
      \fill[yellow,opacity=0.8] (1.5,-0.25) rectangle (2.5,0.25);
    \end{scope}
  }
  \draw[blue,latex-] (0,-2) -- (0,-4) node [below] {Neoprene lid (open)};
  \draw[blue,latex-] (60:2) -- (0, 4) node [above] {ABS acelerometer};
  \draw[blue,<->]    (180:2.5) -- (180:3);
  \node[blue] at     (-3,0) [xshift=-0.25cm,rotate=90,anchor=center] {\SI{4}{cm} to disk edge};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. The solution is awesome. The isometric part is difficult for me to understand. How it works `x={(\xx cm,-\xy cm)},y={(\xx cm,\xy cm)},z={(0 cm,\zy cm)}` in the beginning of the `tikzpicture` and why the values `\xx \xy \zy` are chosen.

Comment: @pablo, these are unitary vectors in the direction of the axes. Their values are calculated in the preamble and you coule define any others the same way (but the tangents of the cylinder in this drawing need isometric axes). In this other post I have a little explanation: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/593344/how-to-rotate-a-3d-axis-some-options-of-the-axis-doesnt-work/593507#593507

Answer (score 1):

If you just want something more relaxed, here's a starting point too, since you wanted explicitely a shape that was *not* a cylinder.

[image: Boxing bag]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.shapes}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        %\draw[help lines] (-1,0) grid (5,12);
        \draw [gray,line width=1pt] plot [smooth cycle] coordinates {(0,0) (.5,8) (3.5,8) (4,0)};
        \draw[brown,line width=1pt]
            (2,6) ellipse (1.9 and 0.5)
            (2,4) ellipse (2.1 and 0.5)
            (2,2) ellipse (2.2 and 0.5);
        \draw[thick,gray,decorate,decoration={shape backgrounds,shape=circle,shape size=4pt,shape sep=3pt}] (2,10) -- (1.5,8.8) (2,10) -- (2.5,8.8) (2,10) --++ (0,1);
        \draw[gray,line width=7pt,cap=round]
            (2.5,11.3) -- (-1,10.2)
            (-2,10.3) -- (0,10)
            (1,10.8) -- (0,8.5) --++ (0,-.5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```